# Reversing the PHP file() function

Tags: php, arrays, file, newline

I converted a .php file to an array using the file() function.
Now I modified the array and I want to put all it contents back to the file (keeping line endings)...
Someone can tell me if there is a function that does the opposite of file()?
I want to bypass the annoying "array to string conversion" way...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.file-put-contents.php) and [`implode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.implode.php):

```
file_put_contents('/your/file.php', implode(PHP_EOL, $fileArray));
```

Comment: Thank you, but I wanted to know if there is a function that somehow reverses directly the process of the file() function.  
I already know how to do it converting it to string with the implode function :(

Comment: Yes with this two functions you get your expected result. There is no direct function which does the opposite of the file() functions.

Comment: Sorry again...your solution was the one that I found before posting my question. I was searching for a single function to get my code optimized. I will mark your answer as accepted though, because it seems that no single function can solve my problem. Thank you